# Why is Google Calendar reminding me it's "Easter Sunday" on 19 Jan 2016?

Tags: google-calendar, google-keep

[image: Google Calendar reminder for Easter Sunday]

A recent update to the Google Calendar app on Android enabled Google Keep reminders to be displayed on the calendar - which is what this looks like. However, I have no such reminder set!? It appears on both the Google calendar widget and inside the app itself.

If I tap-through on the event it does confirm that it is linked to my primary Google account. Whilst I do use Google Keep on this account and do in fact have two reminders set (which do appear on the calendar), there is no such "Easter Sunday" reminder (checked Android, Web Interface and iOS app).

This "reminder" only appears on the Google Calendar *Android* app. It does not appear on the Google Calendar iOS app, which also shows reminders (the other two reminders are shown correctly). It does not show on the web calendar - but this doesn't appear to have the option to show Google Keep reminders.

I've tried a manual refresh/resync, but this makes no difference.

Searching for "easter" or "sunday" within Google Keep on Android (or Web interface / iOS) does not return any results.

If I hide "Reminders" (uncheck the option in calendar settings) for this Google account then this erroneous reminder does indeed disappear from the calendar.

Latest Calendar app - version 5.3.1-109151569-release. Nexus 4, Android 5.1.1

Seems a bit weird.

Any ideas?

Comment: Must be a so called "Easter Egg". Or an early reminder #D Have you verified by the color which calendar it belongs to? Maybe that might give you a clue.

Comment: @Izzy Yes, I had wondered that! lol. Yes, the colour suggested that it belonged to the "Reminders" calendar under my main Google account. I have discovered that this reminder originated from "Google Now", although as to why it suddenly recurred and appeared only in the Google Calendar Android app is a bit of a mystery. (I've updated my question, although maybe I should add that as an answer...)

Comment: I wonder if one has to explicitly acknowledge/dismiss reminders to have them "marked off". While that would explain why it's listed for "today", it wouldn't explain why the same wasn't the case yesterday (or rather "everyday since"). So did you miss to mention that, or did it really only come up on Jan 19th? Apart from that: Yes, please move your "update" to an answer. Even though it does not explain the "why" part, it explains how to get rid of that reminder, and thus provides a solution (even though it might be a temporary one).

Comment: @Izzy Well, I assume I must have dismissed it at the time (Apr 05 2015). It certainly hasn't appeared on the calendar at all until suddenly showing up on Jan 19th! The period between Apr 05 and Jan 19 (289 days) isn't a nice round number of months/weeks and it's a different day of the week (Sun / Tues) so I couldn't say what the recurring frequency was?! But it wasn't even appearing on the "Upcoming" reminders within the Google app. Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appear to have at least discovered where this reminder has originated from: in the Google app (formerly "Google Now"), under "Reminders", there is a "Past" reminder for "Easter Sunday (Apr 05 2015)".

[image: Google App - Past Reminder]
<sup>Past reminder</sup>

However, there is no "Upcoming" (current) reminder listed here for "Easter Sunday" - so nothing should be appearing in the calendar. The two (recurring) Google Keep reminders (mentioned above) are the only two reminders listed under "Upcoming". So, it's still a mystery why this "Easter Sunday" reminder appears to have suddenly recurred after an unusual time period.

#### Partial solution:

Tapping this "Past" entry simply gives the option to delete it. Which I have, and now it's gone from the Google Calendar! It's just a puzzle as to why (and how) it happened?

Comment: Since this is additional information, instead of an answer, it should be added to the question, not posted as an answer.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos Well, I had initially added it to the question, but it does "part answer" the question and Izzy confirmed this is comments above... "please move your "update" to an answer. Even though it does not explain the "why" part, it explains how to get rid of that reminder, and thus provides a solution (even though it might be a temporary one)".